# I set up the discourse via Google Cloud Launcher but it won’t email

Tags: google-cloud-platform, discourse

I set up the discourse via Google Cloud Launcher but it won’t send emails. Not sure how to configure Discourse or Google Cloud :\

Comment: You can always access discourse's admin settings from your instance on this address: <web.com>/admin/site_settings/category/email

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Platform doesn't allow SMTP traffic through default ports: 25, 465, 587. You can check [Google Cloud Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) to configure a third-party mail provider like Sendgrid, Mailgun or Mailjet. If you use Google Apps you can also use it to send email through 465 or 587 ports.

Another alternative could be that you use your own email server on a custom port or using a VPN to bypass that port restriction.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Google Cloud Platform doesn't allow outbound connection to ports 25, 465 and 587.

But you can use 2525.